# MFC how to check window size of other applications?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on a screen record application. I want to capture running applications or computer desktop. when capturing other application, I have to input the window size. But it will crush when the window resized. I have already make a same program on MacOS. In MacOS I can get a notification when the application resized. like this ↓

```
m_axApplication = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
AXObserverAddNotification(m_axObserver, m_axApplication, kAXWindowResizedNotification, nil);
```

Does Windows have the same API in MFC?
Up to now, I will check the window size everytime I get the image of the specified application. It cost too much time and CPU usage. I only want to be noticed when the window resized.
How to make it? Thank you.

Comment: i think you can install a CBT hook on the system, then you can receive notifications like a window is moved or sized.

Comment: Pretty hard to tell, what problem you are trying to solve. I'd argue that querying a window's position and size has trivial overhead compared to taking a full screenshot. You're either guessing, or your profiling is wrong, or your implementation is below standard. We don't know. Anyway, if you do want to get notified about a user making changes to the system, set up a [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) hook.

Comment: If you are receiving a bitmap or png, it should already include the image size, which is probably what you need.